# Flutter build ios android Failed with no errors

Tags: flutter, gradle

It was building fine until I got this build error log.
Any idea of what is going on here please?
I didnt update any package, nor flutter nor dart over the last few months.

```
Flutter 3.3.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 52b3dc25f6 (4 months ago) • 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

```
 Building with sound null safety 

...
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/keyboard_actions-4.2.0/lib/keyboard_actions.dart:322:31: Error: A value of type 'OverlayState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'OverlayState' because 'OverlayState?' is nullable and 'OverlayState' isn't.
 - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
    OverlayState os = Overlay.of(context);
                              ^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.4.53/lib/src/calendar/sfcalendar.dart:10776:71: Error: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't.
 - 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
  RenderAbstractViewport get _stackViewPort => RenderAbstractViewport.of(this);
                                                                      ^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/keyboard_actions-4.2.0/lib/external/keyboard_avoider/bottom_area_avoider.dart:194:27: Error: Method 'getOffsetToReveal' cannot be called on 'RenderAbstractViewport?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
  final offset = viewport.getOffsetToReveal(object, 1.0).offset + overscroll;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/christophevidal/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/christophevidal/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           18.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Even though you didn't *deliberately* update anytning .. a lot of things could *implicitly* update one or another dependency.  Causing "surprises".  For example, maybe you upgraded Android Studio (that bit me recently).  Anyway: see if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71538690/421195) helps.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for your answer. Maybe Visual Studio udpated but it shouldn't impact the build especially since the app is launching properly on both simulators. And this errors are not coming form my code, but from packages that I dont event use in this app.